# Applying Ambient Occlusion in all materials at once

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, ambient-occlusion

I have a scene with lots of materials. I'm using eevee and would like to use Ambient Occlusion. The only way I know is using the Mix Shader on Material Output. Is there any to do it on all scene's materials at once? Thank you!

[image]